Proving existence of matching using hall's condition
Let $A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_n$ be disjoint sets, equal in cardinality. Similarly, let $B_1, B_2, \ldots, B_n$ be disjoint sets, also each equal in cardinality. Assume that $\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} A_i = \bigcup_{j=1}^{n} B_j$. Prove that there exists a permutation $\pi \in S_n$ such that for every $i$ between $1$ and $n$, $A_i \cap B_{\pi(i)} \neq \emptyset$.
I tried to create a bipartite graph between the set U = $\{A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_n\}$ and the set V = $\{B_1, B_2, \ldots, B_n\}$ by connecting each $A_i$ to $B_j$ if their intersection is non-empty and prove that there exists a matching on the set U, however I failed to show that Hall's condition holds, if anyone can help me out, it will be much appreciated.

Can you state Hall's condition, and why you failed to show that it holds?

Hint: you have to use the fact that the $A_i$'s and $B_j$'s are equal in cardinality and that they are disjoint.

Hall's condition in this context says that, for any sub-collection of $r$ sets from $\{A_1,\dots,A_n\}$, call this $A_{i_1},\dots,A_{i_r}$, there exist at least $r$ sets in $\{B_1,\dots,B_n\}$ which intersect at least one of the $A_{i_1},\dots,A_{i_r}$.
Suppose that there are $s$ sets from $\{B_1,\dots,B_n\}$ which intersect at least one of $A_{i_1},\dots,A_{i_r}$. Call these sets $\{B_{j_1},\dots,B_{j_s}\}$. It follows that
$$
\bigcup_{k=1}^r A_{i_k}\subseteq\bigcup_{\ell=1}^s B_{j_\ell}
$$
This is a consequence of $\bigcup_i A_i=\bigcup_j B_j$. Take the cardinalities of both sides of the above, and concluded that $r\le s$, as required.
